# Do I need a bot for each client or can I have one that serves all clients?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, chatbot

I have multiple clients that are using chatbots. I'm currently doing the setup of the chatbots and was wondering if there is a way to have one bot that I can deploy or do I need one for each client and/or service?

I'm new to the chatbot development and Azure. Have been reading on the documentation that Microsoft provides but can't seem to find any solid answers. I've been trying to develop from the samples they provide. I've gotten as far as the QnA answering correctly, but wish to keep implementing other functions and understand how all of it works.

My current code is the samples that Microsoft provides. Like I said I'm fairly new to this.

My expected result would be to have 1 bot that depending on the client/business it will provide the according answers or services.

Comment: Most probably one for each as the bots are most likely stateful

Comment: A “bot” is just a web api endpoint (/api/messages by default). If your clients are different, you can have one deployment hosting multiple api endpoints and have one bot for each client running on each endpoint. Note this is different from channels - a channel is how a bot is exposed. You can expose one bot to multiple channels but these channel share the same bot behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You could technically build 1 bot and connect it to multiple "channels", as is the vocabulary that we use in the Bot Framework. From the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-channels?view=azure-bot-service-4.0):

> The Bot Framework Service, configured through the Azure portal,
>   connects your bot to these channels and facilitates communication
>   between your bot and the user. You can connect to many popular
>   services, such as **Cortana, Facebook Messenger, Kik, and Slack**, as well
>   as several others. The Web Chat channel is pre-configured for you. In
>   addition to standard channels provided with the Bot Connector Service,
>   you can also connect your bot to your own client application using
>   Direct Line as your channel.

Additionally, the Bot Framework is an attempt to allow developers to make bots in a "channels-agnostic" way. However, when developing your bot, you must also bear in mind that certain channels might not support certain UI aspects that others do. For example, FB Messenger might not support Adaptive Cards whereas Microsoft Teams does.

So the TL;DR: you can develop 1 bot and connect it to multiple channels, bearing in mind it's up to you to investigate whether or not the multiple channels support XYZ features.

[image]
Azure portal displaying the different channels that 1 bot is connected to next to star; below additional channels that it suggests you could connect to

Comment: This is kinda true.  It breaks when the channels have architectural differences.  For example, OAuth.  Botframework and Cortana oauth work differently, so you need to build that into your code.  IMHO, you can share a core bot's code and branch, but each bot would be its own service.